# OpenERP 7: How can I add images in sale oder line?

Tags: odoo

how can I add small images in sale.order.line in OpenERP 7? So that each product in orders or quotations has as small image. I'm new on OpenERP and Python and trying to do this for some days now...

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: where do you want this? in the application or in the PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a way. i have described it here:
http://help.openerp.com/question/483/openerp-7-how-can-i-add-images-in-saleoderline/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,There is no way to show images in tree view.So not possible till you hack tree view and make it image supportable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in product.py from product module at line 541 and (following) you can see image set and stored in your product.
In that manner you must define a field in sale.order.line, field related to image field of froduct.
I do not know if works in tree view, but in form view and kanban view works very well.
Thanks